# ASP.Net page Life Cycle

Tags: asp.net, events

I am going through page life cycle.When i referring the following

[image]

there the LoadPostData() method is expressed as (First Try) later (Second Try).What does here try refer to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should refer to the [original image from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx#general_page_lifecycle_stages), it says that it called once for each control
[image]

Answer (score 2):

The page calls this method once BEFORE the page Load event so that all controls on the page or created in the Init event will have their values set from the form post before you start working with them in the Load event code. It calls it a second time because you might have added some dynamic controls during the Load event, and this gives them a chance to get their values set as well.

[This article](http://aspalliance.com/articleViewer.aspx?aId=134&pId=) is a good one that outlines the whole page lifecycle, step by step. You'll see a reference to this second try under the "Raised Events" section.